# Language translation

Tags: php

We have a website that we have been able to translate static texts to 3 local languages using 
locale_en.php
    
locale_hz.php

but we also want to provide translation for the contents posted by users to 3 different local languages. Unfortunately Google hasn't translated our native languages yet. 
We are looking at automatically detecting the texts on the page and provide some form of translation. We already have a mysql table with up to 130,000+ english words.
Any pointers pls? Would really appreciate.

Comment: beware: automatic translation will never be completely accurate.

Comment: http://language.home.sprynet.com/lingdex.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is a rabbit hole you may not be ready to dive down.

Firstly. Automatic translation is not yet at a presentable level. (and some would argue may never be with our current style of computers.) You are overwhelmingly better off showing the wrong language than showing a poorly translated and unprofessional version of someone's native language.

The ideal way to get things translated is to provide an incentive for other users of your site to spend time hand-translating text. Or, using a service that will crowd-source the translation.

One example of that is: http://www.acclaro.com/crowdsourcing-translation

But there are many others.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like a viable option. Pls how can I match strings in the body of the page with hand-translated versions? Knowing fully well that some people might translate only portions of the entire text etc.

Comment: You wouldn't do it string by string. Context is important in language. Structure and syntax change from language to language. What you want is quality writing from native speakers that mirrors the source text's message. Not a word-for-word translation. Otherwise you end up with text like: "I walked to the meat vendor's shop and bought mutton" instead of "I strolled to the butcher shop to buy some lamb shanks." (Or text that reads like Fernando's Answer)

Comment: Thanks. LOL. I appreciate a lot. Is it possible to do a sentence by sentence translation? just looking at a way to make it easier for volunteers to translate. You can imagine how much it will take to translate a content of 3 pages or more.

Comment: This is a hard problem to solve well. There are a lot of hacky-ass solutions that produce shoddy results. Partnering with a crowdsourced solution really is the best option these days, and will make translating 3 pages of text take almost no time at all.

Comment: I really need help doing this. I am looking at using period(fullstop as a separator). Means I have to treat each line of sentence as a unique ID. Pls guys help. Those crowdsourced guys do not have contributors that speak our native languages. Besides it wouldn't hurt to build my own crowd-source translation system.

Comment: Using period won't help much. Mr. Nwoko. Seriously, full text is the way to go. Better context, better prose, better translation.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It always was a problem, the best and accurate way is you have a language file to each language you need, in case os posts it is a little bit complex, if you have time you can translate by time in time, but it is not the best solution.

Another option is, google translate it for you, wordpress system have something on this way, take a look in **word press language plugins**.

Good question, unfortunately there are no good solutions to automatic translations unless you feel comfortable to use google translation for your users.

Good Luck.